# SQL Alchemy and datetime

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have sqlite base with a table Rating.

```
ID|Time|Clicks|
1|2020-04-02 20:20| 250
2|2020-04-03 18:20| 50
3|2020-04-04 22:50| 100
```

My class looks like this:

```
class Rating(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Rating'
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key = True)
    clicks = Column('Clicks', Integer)
    time = Column('Time', Date)
```

I wanna show Clicks for a specific date.

```
date_i_need = datetime.date(2020, 4, 2)

q = test = session.query(Rating).filter_by(time = date_i_need).first()
```

---

I tried to change a type from Date to Datetime and Timestamp, but it always returns None.

Any guess?

Comment: Take into account that SQLite doesn't support date/datetime natively. Most likely SQLalchemy will try to cast the values into a python datetime or date. However, it seems that your data is stored as yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM. Perhaps you could add seconds (:SS) and try the query again with the column set as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `datetime.date` in statement. I think the problem is with syntax. Use `==`:

Please try this:

```
date_i_need = datetime.date(2020, 4, 2)
q_test = session.query(Rating).filter(Rating.time == date_i_need).first()
```